# How to beautify OpenLayers maps

Tags: maps, openlayers

I need to build a web app that renders a Map with different markers.
I think to use a solution as OpenLayers but i would like the maps to have a "better" look (as, for example, http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/). Do you know any library that can be used with OpenLayers to improve its look?

Comment: er, why can't you use leaflet?

Comment: What do you mean with better look, the map tiles or the controls?

Comment: Customizing OpenLayers will give you head ache, it just wasn't meant to look nice. Just use Leaflet instead and you'll be fine. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can style the map buttons as you want using css and images. A popular theme over the blue default button is https://github.com/developmentseed/openlayers_themes (more info http://support.mapbox.com/kb/mapping-101/openlayers-themes)

For feature styling, take a look at http://docs.openlayers.org/library/feature_styling.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily if you are using google maps!

What you must do is copy the source of the openlayers.js script to your publicly available directory, such as `public/js/openlayers.js`. The script is minified. You need to open it up and find where it says `google.maps.Map` and unminify this statement by adding breaks where necessary ( this just makes it more readible ). You then need to add a styles property to the second argument. Some style options can be found for free at this website:

https://snazzymaps.com/explore

In the end you should have a section like this in your customized openlayers.js file:

```
 google.maps.Map(b,{
    center:a?new google.maps.LatLng(a.lat,a.lon):new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
    zoom:this.map.getZoom()||0,
    mapTypeId:this.type,
    disableDefaultUI:!0,
    keyboardShortcuts:!1,
    draggable:!1,
    disableDoubleClickZoom:!0,
    scrollwheel:!1,
    streetViewControl:!1,
    styles: [{"featureType":"road","stylers":[{"hue":"#5e00ff"},{"saturation":-79}]},{"featureType":"poi","stylers":[{"saturation":-78},{"hue":"#6600ff"},{"lightness":-47},{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","stylers":[{"lightness":22}]},{"featureType":"landscape","stylers":[{"hue":"#6600ff"},{"saturation":-11}]},{},{},{"featureType":"water","stylers":[{"saturation":-65},{"hue":"#1900ff"},{"lightness":8}]},{"featureType":"road.local","stylers":[{"weight":1.3},{"lightness":30}]},{"featureType":"transit","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"hue":"#5e00ff"},{"saturation":-16}]},{"featureType":"transit.line","stylers":[{"saturation":-72}]},{}]

}),
```

The downside here is that if the Google API and/or the openlayers.js script ever change you risk breaking your map since you have a static copy of the script. I find that to be a rare event and is a small price to pay for a more beautiful map.

Answer (score 0):

not too sure which parts you want to 'beautify' but you could do worse than having a look at [GeoExt](http://geoext.org/), this combines the UI of sensha Extjs with openlayers.  i've used it to produce some very attractive webGIS applications

hope that is of help

Olly